# How to know all Buttons is show? (editActionsForRowAtIndexPath)

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have this code and I need call a function when all buttons are show. 
How can I tell when the animation that shows the editing actions has finished?'

My code has two button, this is the code:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> [AnyObject]? {

    let confirm = UITableViewRowAction(style: .Normal, title: "Confirm") { action, index in
        //CODE            
    }
    confirm.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()


    let delete = UITableViewRowAction(style: .Normal, title: "Delete") { action, index in
        //code
    }
    delete.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
    return [delete,confirm]
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool {
    // the cells you would like the actions to appear needs to be editable
    return true
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    // you need to implement this method too or you can't swipe to display the actions
}
```

Comment: Be more specific. What exactly do you need to do once the table view shows the edit action buttons after the user left-swipes the cell?

Comment: Hello. How can I tell when the animation that shows the editing actions has finished?'

Comment: Repeating what you already stated in your question isn't being more specific. We already know you wish to know when the animation completes. I asked you what you need to do when the animation completes. Why do you need to know when the animation completes?

Comment: I need to change a  UIImageView when animation is complete